# Magento User Sessions Being Mixed Up

Tags: session, caching, magento, authentication

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following issue.  On our Magento site, enterprise version 1.10.1.1, a user may log in, and it will say another person's name.  Then, if you click on another link, it might go back to your name.  The user sessions are clearly being confused.  Apparently, this is a full-page caching problem, because our full page cache is often invalidated and, if we turn it off, the user sessions no longer mix up. However, turning it off considerably slows down the site.  Switching the sessions from db storage to file storage (and vice versa) did not fix the issue.  Does anyone know what the problem could be or how to solve it?

Thanks very much,

Brenda

Comment: Where user see his name? Maybe it is block added by some extension which didn't implement hole punching for this block?

Comment: The user sees his name in the header for Magento where the Welcome message is.  I'm looking up hole punching now.  Thank you very much.  Hopefully I can turn off the FPC for that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check with Magento for a patch.  I had a similar problem with Gift Certificate field info getting mixed up between sessions.  They provided a patch that resolved the problem.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Thank you very much for letting me know.  I will definitely do that.  Have a great day.

Comment: What is the patch ?, or the block? can you tell me please

Answer (score 1):

In the header.phtml file you should use this to print the user name

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?>
```

Then, you can override the block 'Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome' if you wanna customize your message.

this happens when you use "Full Page Cache" because by default, magento exclude some blocks of the full page cache, and the block 'welcome' is one of they. if you are using customization code and message, the user name will be cached too, and other users will see different user names in this section.

Answer (score 0):

it can be dependence on the cache issue. Try to turn cache off (go to admin, system, cache management and disable all cache).

If issue gone - you need to check cache configuration. If not - you have really session issue.
BTW, where you store sessions (files or DB or memcached?)

Comment: Thanks.  First the sessions were stored in the DB, and then we switched to file storage.  The issue occurred either way.  If we turn off the FPC, then the issue is gone, but it slows down the site.  I just heard of hole punching and will see if I can turn off the FPC for that block (and potentially others).

Comment: You can't turn off the FPC for particular block. Block must implement hole punching to be cached in right way by FPC.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause related to `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor_Default` class, my way is disable it in `config.xml`, edit `src\app\code\core\Enterprise\PageCache\etc\config.xml`:

```
<requests>
<!--  <cms>enterprise_pagecache/processor_default</cms>-->
</requests>
```

Comment: So basically you turned off the full page cache, which is a major performance enhancement in EE. You could have just turned it off in the admin cache controls instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was probably caused by Magento not being able to set proper session parameters if  it was behind a reverse proxy cache like Varnish (I bet it was the case). Whenever using an intermediate caché system you have to make sure you are using the apropiate module in Apache to forward the X_FORWARDED_FOR http header to Magento like mod_rpaf, otherwise Magento will see al requests coming from the same IP and it will not be able to determine correct session isolation as it will think all requests come from the same client.